# Kendo auto complete in a grid to reload on grid page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, autocomplete

I have a kendo auto complete inside a filter functionality of grid column.
every time the page changes i want the auto complete to load according to the page number and page size.

I tried many option but the page number sent to the controller is always 1 and default page size therefore the data in auto complete is always according to 1st page in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful of you to provide code as to better understand how you are attempting to implement this functionality and what you have tried. I recommend you check out the [page method](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/pager/methods/page) `grid.dataSource.page();`. Another option would be to utilize the web-browsers [client-side storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage). I am sure you could probably use something within ASP.NET MVC such as TempData as well.